# Cambiar propiedades del elemento anterior solamente con CSS

Tags: css, css3, selectores-css

Tengo dos elementos `div`, lo que quiero conseguir es que al pasar con el ratón sobre el primer elemento se cambie el color del segundo, y al pasar sobre el segundo se cambie el color del primero. No se si se puede hacer con pseudo clases.

Este es el código que tengo

```css
#div1
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#div1:hover
{
  color: red;
}

#div2
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="div1">Div número 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div número 2</div>

</body>
```

¿Se puede indicar de alguna manera con `CSS` que al pasar sobre el `div` número 1 se cambie el color del `div` número 2 o viceversa?

Comment: Puedes hacer que al pasar sobre el primero cambie el segundo (`#div1:hover + #div2`) pero no al revés. Nunca puedes ir hacia atrás en el DOM en CSS

Comment: Creo que con javascript te será mejor. Puedes usar javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respuesta corta: No se puede ya que al estar al mismo nivel y declarar la propiedad hover en un div solo puedes aplicar estilos a lo que se sitúe en un nivel inferior a dicho div

Respuesta extendida: Puedes hacerlo mediante JavaScript asignando una clase a tu div2 al hacer hover en tu div1 y viceversa:

```js
document.getElementById('div1').onmouseover = function(){
  document.getElementById('div2').classList.add('hover');
}
document.getElementById('div1').onmouseout = function(){
  document.getElementById('div2').classList.remove('hover');
}
document.getElementById('div2').onmouseover = function(){
  document.getElementById('div1').classList.add('hover');
}
document.getElementById('div2').onmouseout = function(){
  document.getElementById('div1').classList.remove('hover');
}
```

```css
#div1.hover{
  color: red;
}
#div2.hover{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div número 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div número 2</div>
```

Comment: Como nota: mejor que mouseover y mouseout, sería usar mouseenter y mouseleave. Si el elemento tiene otro elemento dentro, entonces mouseout se ejecutará cuando se pase por encima de ese elemento interno. Por ejemplo, si uno de los `div` tiene una image, se lanzará mouseover al pasar el ratón por encima del `div` y cuando se pase por encima de la imagen, se lanzará mouseout (incluso cuando está dentro del `div`).

Answer (score 19):

Probando, por puro interés académico y cabezonería, me negaba a creer que no hubiese una manera de hacer lo que necesitas. Y a grandes rasgos no existe una manera de seleccionar un elemento anterior en **CSS** pero se me ocurrió un truquillo para aparentar que lo estás haciendo en este caso en específico.

Envolviendo tus dos `<div>` con otro, podemos seleccionar el `<div>` en el que se está haciendo un `hover` y dentro de este buscar el `<div>` al que no se le esté haciendo un `hover` y a ese aplicarle el cambio de color.

```css
#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}

div:hover div:nth-child(1):not(:hover) {
  color: blue;
}

div:hover div:nth-child(2):not(:hover) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="div1">Div número 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div número 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sí que funciona aunque creo que no puedes modificar los estilos independientemente, es decir, por ejemplo al div1 ponerlo rojo y al div2 ponerlo azul. Buena respuesta

Comment: @David Podrías, he editado la respuesta para que se vea.

Comment: Ahora si que has conseguido la respuesta perfecta para la pregunta, enhorabuena

Comment: genial!!!! mil gracias!!!